# Why isn't there any output when I call out a function I define before?

Tags: python

I type some code like this:

```
def cod():
    return 4

cod()
```

But I get no output from it. Isn't it supposed to output a "4" when I call the function "cod()" ?

Comment: use a `print cod()`

Comment: Only in the interactive interpreter does Python automatically print the value of an expression.

Comment: which python version are you using it perfectly prints the desired output. i tested it in console.

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` something in your function, you have to use it with `print` function, otherwise you can't display it.

```
def cod():
    return 4

print (cod())
```

If you don't `return` something and using `print`, then you can use it same as in your question.

```
def cod():
    print (4)

cod()
```

Note that if you use `print` at second one, you get this output;

```
>>> 
4
None
>>>
```

That's because default `return` is `None` and you are not return something from your function, just printing it. Better using `return`.

Answer (score 1):

`return` does not `print` any value you need to explicitly tell your function to do so

```
print(cod()) #python3
```

or

```
print cod() #python2
```

Python only automatically print  the value of an expression in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print a function value
you should modify your code to be

```
def cod():
    return 4

print cod()
```